# Is it feasible a server-side "hub composition" for ASP.NET Core SignalR?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

Let's say I have some library projects L1, L2, etc. Each one provides for specialized functions. To create a certain web app, I link/refer the desired library to the app project. That app will contain the "glue logic" to make everything working.

Now, each library exposes some SignalR service for its own purposes. Just to make an example, let's say:

```
public class L1_Hub : Hub
{
    public string Concat(string s1, string s2)
    {
        return s1 + s2;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class L2_Hub : Hub
{
    public double Calc(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

What I would like is to share a single hub connection. That's for several reasons.

However, if I map both the classes to the same pattern, SignalR will raise an error, due the ambiguity.

```
app.MapHub<L1_Hub>("/hub");
app.MapHub<L2_Hub>("/hub");
```

Having the ability to map a hub/method by some kind of attribute, it would be perfect. But I couldn't find any.

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Why you want to map different hub to same path?  One Path should just map with one hub.

Comment: @BrandoZhang basically to save connections. At the moment (legacy code) I use one connection for all the services. However, by splitting the code in several libs, I'd like to find a solution to keep just one connection.

Comment: For signalr service, each client connection will have a server connection. I don't know what you mean about just keep one connection. All in all,  if you want to just keep one connection, please put the method all inside the one hub method.

Comment: @BrandoZhang have a look at my example: the server app is made up with two or more libraries, and each one offers some SignalR services. That is, each library should define its own Hub-derived class. Now, if I *must* create a hub endpoint for each library (said N its count), that means the server will keep N connections just for ONE client. Hence, N times more connections as I had just one single hub for all the SignalR services. In other words, when 100 clients are logged, I'll have N*100 connection instead of just 100.

Comment: For this kind of senior, I suggest you could consider using the Azure signalr service, which just keep 5 connections for server connection and Azure signalr service will help checking the other connections. Otherwise , I don't think you could put multiple different hubs inside just one endpoint.

Comment: @BrandoZhang interesting scenario, but at the moment I must consider the app as working even in an off-cloud envoronment. Thanks

Comment: But we couldn't map multiple hub class to same endpoint, it's impossible.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I briefly browsed the source code and it seems to me a lack of design. The fact is that the useful pieces are the methods, not the class. Take for example the APIs: the controller definition vs the "minimal" approach. That is, I'm pretty sure it could be done a different approach for mapping the methods for the SinglaR, as well.